# What is difference between label.configure(image=value) and label.image=value?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

wd = Tk()

def func_open():
    fname = askopenfilename(parent=wd, filetypes=( ("gifs","*.gif"), ("alls","*.*") ))
    photo1 = PhotoImage( file = fname )
    pLabel.configure( image = photo1 )
    pLabel.image=photo1

temp = PhotoImage()
pLabel = Label(wd, image = temp )
pLabel.pack(expand=1)

mainMenu = Menu(wd)
wd.config(menu=mainMenu)
fileMenu = Menu(mainMenu)
mainMenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open",command=func_open)

wd.mainloop()
```

2 lines of code above,
`pLabel.configure( image = photo1 )`
`pLabel.image=photo1`
if i remove one of these, `func_open()` can't print image file.
To me, it seems like both line says same thing,
as `pLabel.configure( image = photo1 )`   put image through argument photo1
and `pLabel.image=photo1` is directly put photo1 to pLabel's image.
I tried search that .configure() method but i couldn't get any understandable imformation.

Comment: As the function says, `.configure(image=...)` is to configure the `image` option which defines the image to be shown. Whereas `.image` is an attribute (it can be any name) to save the reference of the image so that the image will not be garbage collected when the image is configured inside a function.  `.image = ...` is not necessary if the image is configured in the global scope.

Comment: Then why `.configure( image = photo1 )` is valid, not `.configure( image = pLabel.image )` ?  
And the code `.image= ...` is written below `.configure()` so how `.configure()` get that? as i know, codes are processed in order of written...

Comment: Read my comment carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgets have internal configuration options that control its appearance and behavior. When you call the `configure` method, you are giving one of those options a value. Thus, `pLabel.configure( image = photo1 )` sets the `image` option to the value of the `photo1` variable.

When you do `pLabel.image=photo1`, you are creating a new instance variable on the `pLabel` python object named `image` and setting it to the value of the `photo1` variable. The underlying tkinter widget has no knowledge of this attribute, and isn't affected by this attribute.

This is a common idiom for saving a reference to the image. The use of the word `image` is completely arbitrary, using `pLabel.xyzzy=photo1` or `pLabel.save_this=photo1` would solve the exact same problem.

For more information see [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)